# Making the UITextField take the first responder

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a view with a `UITextField` in it. When I click into the "textfield", I call a method that calls up the keyboard and adds a toolbar on with a button and new `UITextField`.

The method I use is this:

```
public static void SetKeyboardEditorWithCloseButton(UITextField txt, UIKeyboardType keyboardType)
    {
        var toolbar = new UIToolbar
        {
            BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black,
            Translucent = true,

        };
        txt.KeyboardType = keyboardType;
        toolbar.SizeToFit();

        var text = new UITextView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 200, 32))
        {
            ContentInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero,
            KeyboardType = keyboardType,
            Text = txt.Text,
            UserInteractionEnabled = true
        };
        var textField = new UIBarButtonItem(text);
        text.Layer.CornerRadius = 4f;
        text.BecomeFirstResponder();

        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(StringUtils.GetString("Common.Done"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done,
                             (s, e) =>
            {
                text.ResignFirstResponder();
                txt.ResignFirstResponder();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Text))
                    txt.Text = text.Text;
            });

        toolbar.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        toolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[]{ doneButton, textField }, true);

        txt.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }
```

The intent is that when this is called the `UITextField` on the toolbar should become the first responder. Am I doing this correctly or should I be doing something else to force the `UITextField` on the toolbar to become the first responder. Resigning the first responder from text obviously closes the keyboard.

Comment: Important info: What framework are you using? UITextField would normally imply plain old Objective-C/CocoaTouch.

Comment: Let';s see .. on storyboard, click on the TextField.  Now click on the outlets (top right).  Did you remember to set the delegate?

Comment: I'm using Monotouch (Xamarin.iOS) - so anything that works there should work the same. @JoeBlow - not using a storyboard, bog standard ViewController for it.

Comment: OK - Same deal, you have to 100% check that you connected all the "delegate" things -- you know, by dragging.  You know ... sort of like this .. http://cdn4.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ConnectingAppDelegate.jpg  (NOT exactly as in that visual example .. drag it to **your class** in question, the view basically)